# Display select values with Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

Hi in the following laravel project I have to display a select on a database inside a table (the project uses laravel), the blade must send a php parameter called (IdUtente) to then be displayed inside the blade in a table, like can I do to make the post call with the parameter and then display the values ​​within the table?

** GestioneArticoli.blade.php**

```
    <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">

     <thead>
     <th>IdArticolo</th>
     <th>Codice Articolo</th>
     <th>Prezzo</th>
     <th>Modifica</th>
     <th>Elimina</th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>

      <tr>
      <?php
        foreach ($Articoli as $art) 
        {
         echo "<td>";
         echo $art->IdArticolo;
         echo "</td>";
         echo "<td>";
         echo $art->CodiceArticolo;
         echo "</td>";
         echo "<td>";
         echo $art->Prezzo;
         echo "</td>";
         echo "<td>
          <p data-placement='top' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Edit'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' data-title='Edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></button></p>";
         echo "</td>";
         echo " <td>";
         echo "  <p data-placement='top' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete'><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' data-title='Delete' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></button></p>";
         echo "</td>";
         }
       ?>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::post('recuperoarticoliutente', 'Articolo@GetArticoli');
```

**Controllers/Articolo.php**

```
class Articolo extends Controller
{
    public function GetArticoli($iduser)
    {
        $articoli = DB::table('Articolo')->where('IdUtente', '=', $iduser)->get();
        return view('gestionearticoli', ['Articoli' => $articoli]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//your view

```
 <thead>
 <th>IdArticolo</th>
 <th>Codice Articolo</th>
 <th>Prezzo</th>
 <th>Modifica</th>
 <th>Elimina</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>

  <tr>
  <?php
    foreach ($articoli as $art) 
    {
     echo "<td>";
     echo $art->IdArticolo;
     echo "</td>";
     echo "<td>";
     echo $art->CodiceArticolo;
     echo "</td>";
     echo "<td>";
     echo $art->Prezzo;
     echo "</td>";
     echo "<td>
      <p data-placement='top' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Edit'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' data-title='Edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></button></p>";
     echo "</td>";
     echo " <td>";
     echo "  <p data-placement='top' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete'><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' data-title='Delete' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></button></p>";
     echo "</td>";
     }
   ?>
</tr>
```

//route. change post to get and specify the url id

```
Route::get('recuperoarticoliutente/{id}', 'Articolo@GetArticoli');
```

//controller

```
class Articolo extends Controller
{
    public function GetArticoli($iduser)
    {
        $data['articoli'] = DB::table('Articolo')->where('IdUtente', '=', $iduser)->get();
        return view('gestionearticoli', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I call to populate the $articoli array inside the blade?

Answer (score 0):

in your view ou can write a foreach control structures to loop though the record in your db

```
<thead>
 <th>IdArticolo</th>
 <th>Codice Articolo</th>
 <th>Prezzo</th>
 <th>Modifica</th>
 <th>Elimina</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>

  <tr>

    @foreach ($articoli as $art) 

     echo "<td>";
     echo $art->IdArticolo;
     echo "</td>";
     echo "<td>";
     echo $art->CodiceArticolo;
     echo "</td>";
     echo "<td>";
     echo $art->Prezzo;
     echo "</td>";
     echo "<td>
      <p data-placement='top' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Edit'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' data-title='Edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></button></p>";
     echo "</td>";
     echo " <td>";
     echo "  <p data-placement='top' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete'><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' data-title='Delete' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></button></p>";
     echo "</td>";

    @endforeach
</tr>
```